# Clickable Links in Textmate?

Tags: macos, mac, textmate

How can I get a link to be clickable in PlainText in Textmate. Currently it gets underlined, but is not clickable.

Comment: So you can create the link but it will not do the desired behaviour?

Comment: If I type http://b.com it is a link, but there is no way to navigate to it. I wish to navigate to it from Textmate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Position cursor on url and press return (not enter on mac book it is fn + enter). This will work only on links that are detected ant therefore highlighted (like `http://b.com`, it won't work for simple `b.com`)

Comment: Really? I'm going to check this right now.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: It's actually bound to enter  ( fn-↩ on keyboards with no dedicated enter key). urls are handled by an injection grammar from hyperlink helper.

Comment: This is the most counter-intuitive thing ever. I always have to Google the answer. Glad it is easy to find though.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer relies on OS X 10.6 and its new and improved Services feature.

To open URLs from TextMate all you need is a couple keyboard shortcuts. If your cursor is anywhere within the URL or at the beginning (not at the end), you can select the whole URL by going to Edit -> Select -> Current Scope or using the keyboard shortcut ⌃⌥B. Then, in the TextMate -> Services menu, click Open URL in the Internet section. You can set a global keyboard shortcut for this by going to the Services Preference Pane and typing in a shortcut for the Open URL service. I use ⌃⌘L.

Therefore, to very quickly open a URL from TextMate, place your cursor in the URL, type ⌃⌥B and ⌃⌘L. That might even be faster than clicking it if it were clickable.

Comment: Thanks Fideli, when I get 10.6 up and running (tempted to try today, so if I never come back it means my computer caught fire) I'll give this a shot and mark it best answer if it works.

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: please check the new best answer that just came in. Very cool.