# Hyperlink to file in TextMate

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, mac, latex, textmate-2

I use TextMate to edit LaTeX documents. Let's say I have the file foo.xlsx on my Desktop. In my .tex file how can I add a hyperlink to foo.xlsx, so that when I click on the link, the file is opened with Excel?

This is the contents of my .tex file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua [foo.xlsx].
```

When I click on foo.xlsx within my .tex file, I want foo.xlsx to open with Excel. Does anyone know how I can set this up in TextMate? I'm on a Mac (Yosemite).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clickable Links in Textmate?](http://superuser.com/questions/78784/clickable-links-in-textmate)

Comment: [Markdown reference links in TextMate](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/09/markdown-reference-links-in-textmate/)